# Import custom requirejs module in ts file

Tags: javascript, typescript, requirejs

I have custom made AMD module, `foo`, compiled by typescript in my requirejs config.

From what I've read, `import foo = require('./foo');` would suffice in order to import it in another requirejs module.

My goal is simply to make the compiler include it so that my code compiles to something like `define(["require", "exports", "foo"...`

**requirejs config:**

```
// ...
paths: {
    'foo': 'core/foo' 
}
// ...
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "amd",
    "removeComments": true
  }
}
```

**foo.ts**

```
class foo {
}

export = foo;
```

Here is my problem. When I try to import it, the compiler complains:

**otherfile.ts**

```
import foo = require('./foo'); // error: [ts] cannot find module ./foo
```

I'm using VS code with typescript version 1.8.10.